# Jira Conventions and Best-Practices

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

I have been using Jira since 6months but haven;t been through any document related to various options available and how to use them for maximum output.

There must be some conventions that help in better tracking of the issue.
For instance, Logging work, Linking issues, creating sub-tasks.

It would be of help if you can share some of the features (and the conventions) that you follow while using Jira. It may vary from team-to-team but there must be some generic rules which can be followed.

Any feedback would be of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of our conventions for using JIRA:

- Each project has its own JIRA project.
- We use the Greenhopper plugin for Scrum planning.
- There is no development without a JIRA issue assigned. If needed, Developer add issues on their own.
- Commits contain the JIRA ID (for FishEye integration).
- Language of JIRA comments.
- When working on an issue, it's state is changed to "in progress"
- Findings, Problems, Things Done are documented as comments.

Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219138/best-practice-of-using-components-in-jira-projects).